# FlatList not rendering Images

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have react native code to display list of Images of a Cart, When the user natigate to PaymentScreen, The screen should display list of Items of cart, for which I used FlatList, Before the FlatList renders the {cardItems} should be populated, for which I used useEffect. Despite I am getting 'Cannot read large of undefined' What is wrong in the code, I am not getting it.

```
       function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {
    const cartItems = [];



    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            (_forEachKey().then( (k) => {
                //alert('TO'+ JSON.stringify(k));
                k.forEach((v) => {
                    //console.log('Key:' +v);
                    _getData(it.id.value).then((res) => {
                        cartItems.push(res);
                        alert('<<<<CART---'+ cartItems.length);  
                    })
                })
            }))
        });
        return unsubscribe;
      }, [navigation]);

    const { confirmPayment, loading } = useConfirmPayment();
    const {it} = route.params;

    return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
        data={cartItems}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Image style={{height: imageHeight/2, width: imageWidth}} source={{ uri: item.picture.large }}/>}
      />
    </View>);
}

export default PaymentScreen;
```

Alert JSON is as follows:

```
{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"Miss","first":"Dana","last":"Holland"},"location":{"street":{"number":7497,"name":"Shady Ln Dr"},"city":"Hobart","state":"New South Wales","country":"Australia","postcode":7896,"coordinates":{"latitude":"39.0167","longitude":"23.6056"},"timezone":{"offset":"+11:00","description":"Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia"}},"email":"dana.holland@example.com","login":{"uuid":"92740bc7-0d36-43fb-873f-ace45d108ceb","username":"silverswan770","password":"lily","salt":"NW3rt2hb","md5":"76c26dd356fb50310326b3eb9c25d251","sha1":"05c917289c3af2dd6c513c7ec7c45406a04227b8","sha256":"8ad4ed484a91c770b6509978f86afca63e1f9b6ed446a3e66bf78a08f228152c"},"dob":{"date":"1999-04-24T11:51:49.452Z","age":24},"registered":{"date":"2005-06-15T05:05:19.431Z","age":18},"phone":"08-0402-1305","cell":"0465-571-467","id":{"name":"TFN","value":"415401963"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/91.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/91.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/91.jpg"},"nat":"AU"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `useState` for cartItems.

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
...
  setCartItems(...)
...
})

<FlatList
   data={cartItems}
   renderItem={({item}) => ...}
/>
```

See [Updating Arrays in State](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) for details.